# Will Google Punish me for Copying an Attachment from a Manufacturer's Website and Sharing it on My Website?

Tags: seo

I have a problem that I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere. I am a distributor and I sell products of different manufacturers on my website.

Now, I am creating a new webpage where I am mentioning some of the items that I am buying from manufacturer brand. I want to include a spec sheet(a pdf attachment) on my website but it's a long specification sheet and the manufacturer already has it on their website. So what I am going to do is, copy that pdf attachment spec sheet and share it on my website.

Will google punish me for that and is it bad for SEO?

Comment: I'd recommend disallowing the spec sheet from being crawled, but even it Googlebot crawls it, it will detect it as a duplicate from the manufacturer and choose not to index the copy on your site.  It won't hurt the rest of your site at all.

Comment: But if the google bot indexes the page, it will see as duplicate content, right? So if Google thinks it is a bad practice, that would end up hurting my SEO ranking on Google which would have a big impact on my website as my business heavily depends on google ads.

Comment: If it is in a separate PDF it won't affect your page.  In any case, duplicate content rarely hurts the SEO of unique content.   Google only punishes sites for egregiously spammy duplicate content.

Comment: What do you mean when you say seperate pdf? 

I am creating a button and users are able to open that pdf attachment within the page by clicking the button.